# Django CMS PlaceholderField

Tags: django-cms, djangocms-text-ckeditor

I am trying to integrate Django CMS CKEditor as a field option into my custom model where I need the CMS Plugins such as Filer and Link. I've encountered an PlaceholderField but unsure what this is actually supposed to be used for and haven't been able to find any good tutorials on it.

What is PlaceholderField used for ? I've added it into my model but unsure how to link it with the html field.

````
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    content = PlaceholderField('content')```
````

Answer (score 0):

The `PlaceholderField` brings the functionality you usually get from CMS page templates when you do `{% placeholder "content" %}` to your own models.

This is great for an app like news, where a news article might have all kinds of different content. Using a `PlaceholderField` would mean that in the template rendering your news object you could do something like;

```
<h1>{{ object.title}}</h1>
<div class="article_content">
    {% render_placeholder object.content "640" %}
</div>
```

Then in the frontend, looking at that page, you'd get the same structure view from CMS showing your placeholder from which you can add CMS plugins to it.

This is a brilliant way to bring all the third party plugins, as well as any you've made for CMS pages to your models.

The docs on this are here; http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/placeholders.html

Comment: Thanks for clarify that. My model declaration is as follows ```class News(CMSPlugin):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    left_content_placeholder = PlaceholderField('left_content')
``` and I do the ```{% render_placeholder instance.left_content_placeholder "640" %}``` inside my template however I have no option to add a plugin to the News plugin which I just created, what can I be missing?

Comment: So my understanding of it is that it is an attribute on a model which allows us to define a section i.e. I have a news plugin having multiple placeholder on this (i.e. one for left column and one for right) it would allow me to basically drop any plugin into these places and they act like placeholders on a template expect they are on plugin level? Is this correct?

Comment: Ah I see. That won't work. But it doesn't need to also. `PlaceholderField` is for normal Models. If you've written a plugin which you want to then contain plugins you can just define `News` as the parent class of the child plugins. Then the children can be added under a news plugin. Docs are here; http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/custom_plugins.html#nested-plugins

Comment: I've implemented PlaceholderField and it works fine except that any non admin user cannot access it. Would you please have a look at https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/5178#issuecomment-669904244. Do you have a solution?